# How can I remove an entire HTML tag (and its contents) by its id using a regex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am not very good with Regex but I am learning.

I would like to remove some html tag by the id name. This is what I have so far :

```
let test = `
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="testArea" style="display:block">
        <div>
            <tale>...blah</table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
`

let testReplace = test.replace('<div id="testArea" style="display:block">.*?</div>', '');
```

I want to replace the testArea area.

What am I doing wrong? I have try a lot of set without success.

Comment: you want to replace or remove it all?

Comment: Is it important to do it via regex, or other approaches are also acceptable?

Comment: I think I'll have to proceed with regular expressions.

Comment: Afzal K., I need to replace the testArea div area.

Comment: In order to use regex, the first argument for `replace()` must be a [`RegExp` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#flags_in_constructor), so it should be `/<div id="testArea" style="display:block">.*?<\/div>/s`. The flag `s` in the end is [dotAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/dotAll#), which will also looks for the newline characters.

I would suggest to use other approach other than regex, because it would be challenging if the testArea element contains closing `</div>` tag.

Comment: /<div id="testArea" style="display:block">.*?<\/div>/s 

thx!!